# Spark when function compare with integer value

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, hadoop, dataset

```
def takeArray(c: Column): Column = {

      when(size(c) === lit(4), c.getItem(2)).
        when(size(c) === lit(2), c.getItem(1))
      when(size(c) === lit(0), lit(0)).otherwise(lit(-100))

    }
    df.withColumn("new_col", takeArray(col("id")))
      .select( col("id"),size(col("id")), col("new_col")).show()
```

function takeArray - based on length of array, it will take the index and return value.

```
+------------+--------+-------+
|          id|size(id)|new_col|
+------------+--------+-------+
|[1, 2, 3, 4]|       4|   -100|
|      [3, 4]|       2|   -100|
|          []|       0|      0|
+------------+--------+-------+
```

Updated:

Adding Schema

```
root
 |-- id: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
```

i am getting above ouput, which is wrong. first row id column size is 4 and it should match with first when clause and should return "2".. but it is returning -100 . Any idea ? why i am getting weired answer?

example 2 :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

def lifeStage(col: Column): Column = {
  when(col < 13, "child")
    .when(col >= 13 && col <= 18, "teenager")
    .when(col > 18, "adult")
}


val df = Seq(10, 15, 25).toDF("age")

df
  .withColumn(
    "life_stage",
    lifeStage(col("age"))
  )
  .show()

+---+----------+
|age|life_stage|
+---+----------+
| 10|     child|
| 15|  teenager|
| 25|     adult|
+---+----------+
```

Solution: issue with dot(.) . miss to add when clause

Comment: Can you post your df schema & sample data here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing one dot after 2nd when condition. Please check below code.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def takeArray(c: Column): Column = {
      when(size(c) === lit(4), c.getItem(2)).
      when(size(c) === lit(2), c.getItem(1))    // here you are missing one dot, if you add dot here your code will work.
      when(size(c) === lit(0), lit(0)).otherwise(lit(-100))
}
df.withColumn("new_col", takeArray(col("id"))).select( col("id"),size(col("id")), col("new_col")).show()


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

+------------+--------+-------+
|          id|size(id)|new_col|
+------------+--------+-------+
|[1, 2, 3, 4]|       4|   -100|
|      [3, 4]|       2|   -100|
|          []|       0|      0|
+------------+--------+-------+

takeArray: (c: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.Column

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def takeArray(c: Column): Column = {
      when(size(c) === lit(4), c.getItem(2)).
      when(size(c) === lit(2), c.getItem(1)).    // here I have added . now it is showing result as expected.
      when(size(c) === lit(0), lit(0)).otherwise(lit(-100))
}
df.withColumn("new_col", takeArray(col("id"))).select( col("id"),size(col("id")), col("new_col")).show()


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

+------------+--------+-------+
|          id|size(id)|new_col|
+------------+--------+-------+
|[1, 2, 3, 4]|       4|      3|
|      [3, 4]|       2|      4|
|          []|       0|      0|
+------------+--------+-------+

takeArray: (c: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.Column

scala>
```

Comment: @Srinivas..I am doing the same in function.. what is the difference

Comment: I have updated answer, took your code & added print method to show you where your code is failing.

Comment: thanks for ur reply.. updated another example - Passing Column - NOT value..

Comment: Still wondering why takeArray function is NOT working as expected.. Already tried with inline when clause.but when i pass col value to another function, results are not expected

Comment: Also try this in takeArray function  when(size(c) > 3, "Success").otherwise("failure") - working as expected..is issue some related to comparision ..

Comment: I got your problem now. You are missing one dot after this line - when(size(c) === lit(4), c.getItem(2)).when(size(c) === lit(2), c.getItem(1))

Comment: because of that you are always getting same value. Please accept this answer & upvote if this solution works ..:)